# Benefit of only having MFA challenge on the very first login

Tags: password-management, multi-factor

I'm trying to select a suitable password store for a team - one of my main requirements is that users be authenticated via a removable key file rather than simply a master password.

I have been using KeePass for years, and it seems to me that the key file option for authentication represents strong security. In one team, we mandate that the key file must be stored on removable media, and must be removed from the device once authentication is complete. Sadly, KeePass is unsuitable in other ways (e.g. inability to share subsets of passwords, basic interface)

I arrived at 1Password, based on the fact it has MFA and accomodates Duo and Titan keys. However - since setting up MFA and a Titan key, I've learned that it only requires additional factors *the first time the user logs in on a particular device*. After that, apparently, the device is verified and it no longer challenges.

I fail to see how this is much help at all - it seems to me that if a device is stolen after verification, we're back to the master password alone. Which either has to then be memorable, or stored elsewhere. In my case (ironically) this is in KeePass. This is a headache that no team member or senior manager would be prepared to accept.

Have I understood this correctly, or have I missed an important detail?

Comment: I refocused the question to just the one question. Questions of the type "is there a product/service that does X?" are off-topic.

Comment: Have you read 1Password's response to this query? https://www.reddit.com/r/1Password/comments/v7pl6q/how_to_make_desktop_app_ask_me_for_mfa_code_every/ (they appear to get asked this a lot)